# Can google/twitter/facebook deny an app access to users who signed up using them

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, google-signin

If you add a feature of sign in using either google/twitter/facebook or any other third party platform, can that platform make it impossible for registered users on your platform to sign in to your platform?

What power do these platforms have to the users that use them to sign in to another platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your platform only allows authentication via a certain platform, like Facebook, then your authentication feature will solely depend on whether the user is able to authenticate via that platform, in this example, Facebook.

If you provide features for authentication to several platforms, but not one of your own, then even the user is denied access to another platform, he/she will still be able to access your platform, as long as he/she is not denied access from all the platforms.

However, if you provide authentication feature of your own, then as a minimum the users will be able to authenticate via that, even if they are denied access to all the platforms that you support.

Comment: Another question. Can this platforms see the number of people who have authenticated to a certain platform using their platforms? Can these platforms block already authenticated users on your platform from accessing your platform if they used them to sign in?

Comment: If they can access their account only via a third-party platform, then yes. But if you provide a feature of account recovery via sending an email with a token to them, then they may still recover their account.